# How to enable scrolling inside an `overflow: hidden` div

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I've implemented a kanban board with `react-beautiful-dnd`. It works the way I want.

I would like to be able to use this board inside a `div` container that has `overflow: hidden`. However, doing so prevents from dragging Cards in columns that are outside of the viewport, the screen does not scroll horizontally to the right anymore.

I'm simplifying the issue, the reason I need this is because I'm using a Layout component which `content` component is a div with `overflow: hidden`.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-moser-y05q4xk6j1) that demo the issue

Basically, this works, I can drag-drop Card to the right and it will scroll horizontally :

```
<div style={{ overflow: 'unset}} >
    <Kanban />
<div>
```

This does not:

```
<div style={{ overflow: 'hidden }} >
    <Kanban />
<div>
```

Maybe there is a way to reset the first div as such?:

```
<div style={{ overflow: 'hidden }} >
    <div style={{ }}> // something here to reset container div?
        <Kanban />
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I did, but not with `react-beautiful-dnd`. It's a pity. I ended up using `@richardrout/react-smooth-dnd`, and when importing `import {
    Container
} from '@richardrout/react-smooth-dnd'`, use it this way: `<Container
                disableScrollOverlapDetection={true} ...></...>`

Comment: It's a branch of `react-smooth-dnd`.  You'll have all the doc there: https://github.com/kutlugsahin/react-smooth-dnd